# how to set $Index to 1 every ng-repeat call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr ng-repeat="x in AppliedJob">
    <td>{{x.JobName}}</td>
 <td>  <span class="dropdown" ng-repeat="y in AppliedCenter|  unique: 'Location' " ng-if="y.JobName==x.JobName">
 {{$index+1}}){{y.Location}}                      
 </span> </td></tr> </table>
```

Output of above code

```
1) Tester    :  1)India 2)USA 3)Australia
2) Developer :  4)Japan 5)China
```

Required Output

```
1) Tester    :  1)India 2)USA 3)Australia
2) Developer :  1)Japan 2)China
```

I want to set `$Index` to `1`.

Comment: why you do not try with local variable intialize in html page using ng-init and try to intialize outer loop looping at every time intialize with 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you're filtering using `ng-if` which is not affect array and it's indexes, it just removes the element from DOM. You should use [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead of `y.JobName==x.JobName` comparison in `ng-if` so yours `ng-repeat` expression should be like this `y in AppliedCenter | unique: 'Location' | filter: { JobName: x.JobName }`. See example:

```js
angular
.module('Test', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.cities = ["New York", "LA"];
  $scope.jobs = [{ name: "QA", city: "New York"}, { name: "Frontend", city: "New York"}, {name: "Backend", city: "New York"}, {name: "DBA", city: "LA"}, { name: "QA", city: "LA"}];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="city in cities">
        <td ng-bind="city"></td>
        <td>
          <span ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:{city: city}">{{($index + 1) + ")" + job.name}} </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $index work but  in json duplicate entry/value so when i use ng-if it shows only one but in filter its show all then how it distinct ex. like see   LA  1)DBA  2)DBA  3)QA  4)QA

Comment: You should combine `filter` with `unique` and it will remove dublicates.